# Why do i get an error for (top method and isempty method) saying cannot find symbol?

Tags: java, stack

I wrote this code but I am getting error on **isEmpty** method saying cannot find symbol?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ITDLinkedStack{

public int peek() 
{ 
 if (isEmpty()) // this is where i get the error
 throw new RuntimeException("Peek attempted on empty stack");
 else
return top.data;

}

   }
```

Comment: What are you calling `isEmpty()` on? You haven't passed in an argument or checked it against any object

Comment: you gave incomplete code, or there is no `isEmpty()` method in your code

Comment: Please define the isEmpty() method.. like:public Stack() {
        first = null;
        N = 0;
    }

   /**
     * Is the stack empty?
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code that you posted, you excluded the rest of the code. If you add it in your code, your line will work!

```js
 if (isEmpty()) // this is where i get the error
 throw new RuntimeException("Peek attempted on empty stack");
 else
return top.data;
```

Comment: You can also look up basic push pop peek methods on google. There may be a few variations but they should work for you.